# Problem With DLL File

Tags: files

I want to Run Emulator 8086 on Ubuntu , but it's told me that is MSVBVM60.DLL missing so I download this DLL file to my computer , but it's still telling me that  MSVBVM60.DLL ismissing

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally be using Linux programs rather than Windows ones.

MSVBVM60.DLL is a VB6 runtime and can best be installed into wine by first installing the winetricks package either from the software centre of from a command line

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Then

```
winetricks vb6run
```

Sources [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=724943).

Comment: I do all steps but he is telling me that this file does not exisit !!!

Comment: I've just tested this on a 13.04 test machine.  It launches Firefox to download a file which you must copy to exactly where it tells you then run it again and its working for.  What version of Ubuntu are you running? What do you do to get the error message and what is the exact error message?